# Show $y(x)=(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)$ is a solution of $y'+p(x)y=g(x).$ when $y_{1}(x),y_{2}(x)$ are solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Differential Equations:**

$y_1(x), y_2(x)$ are solutions of $y'+p(x)y=g(x)$ when $p,g$ are continuous functions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Show $y(x)=(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)$ is a solution of $y'+p(x)y=g(x).$

If i subtitute $y(x)=(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)$ in $y'+p(x)y=g(x)$ i get : $y'+p(x)[(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)]=g(x)$.

If $c=0$ or $c=1$ the equation in correct.

I know $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ has no $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$

But I can't see how it helps me to show it  $\forall c \in \mathbb R$.

Help, please?

Comment: Remember $(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)=y$.

Comment: @xpaul   Sorry, I am new to this, I cant see it.

Comment: In $y'+p(x)[(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)]=g(x)$, $(1-c)y_{1}(x)+cy_2(x)=y$ and then you have $$y'+p(x)y=g(x).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y(x)=(1-c)y_1(x)+cy_2(x)$, then $y'(x)=(1-c)y_1'(x)+cy_2'(x)$. So you should have $[(1-c)y_1'(x)+cy_2'(x)]+p(x)[(1-c)y_1(x)+cy_2(x)]=g(x)$, which can be rearranged as $(1-c)[y_1'(x)+p(x)y_1(x)]+c[y_2'(x)+p(x)y_2(x)]=g(x)$.

I leave the rest to you, as now, it should be relatively easy to see how to complete the proof.